# Gradle DSL method not found: 'multiDexEnabled()'

Tags: android, gradle

Error:

> Error:(22, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'multiDexEnabled()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Project' may be using a
>   version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The
>   build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html), multiDexEnabled goes inside the  defaultConfig, buildType, or productFlavor sections of your Gradle build file.  You have it inside android, which is not valid.